# Error while applying TimeDistributed to InceptionResnetV2 in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

```
x=Input(shape=(10,299,299,3))
y=TimeDistributed(InceptionResnetV2(include_top=False,weights='./weights.h5'))(x)
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
Failed to convert object of type <type 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (-1, 10, None, None, 1536). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why we're getting this error, but it's possible to use this workaround:

```
x=Input(shape=(10,299,299,3))

#join the steps dimension with the samples dimension, the model won't see a difference    
y=Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(-1,299,299,3)))(x)

#use a regular inception model
y = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False,weights=None)(y)

#bring back the hidden steps dimension
y = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(-1,10,8,8,1536)))(y)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me get around that error. But now I am getting a dimensions error- `Error when checking target: expected lambda_2 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 1)`

Comment: The problem is you `Y`, what do you want to do with this model? Your model outputs `(batch, 10, 8, 8, 1536)`, and you `Y` is `(8,1)`, these must match.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I did not get that the error was talking about Y. Solved my problem

Comment: Your model must then output `(None, 1)`.... but is this label binary? (two classes only?)

Comment: yeah two classes only

Comment: You can (among many many options), add a `Flatten()` and a `Dense(1)` at the end for that. (Watch the "activation" of the dense layer, it must match the range of `Y`)